# PHP - PEAR Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer - Merging columns fails after Row ~259?

Tags: php, excel, pear, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I'm using PEAR's Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer to, well, write Excel files. I'm encountering a rather odd error, though. Without fail, my script stops merging cells around row ~260, plus/minus maybe 2.

I am reading values from a database with a variable starting position. Though the row at which the merging stops to work is not the same for every list of database entries, it does not vary when the script is run from the same starting position.

I understand that I'm not making any sense at all, so [attached is an example generated Excel file](http://www.mediafire.com/?yzzfr481vtydfwz). ;) Notice how from line 261 onward, the cells don't merge as they do in the several rows prior.

I am at a complete loss as to what can be causing this. My script is very large and database-dependent too, so it's not very well suited for providing here, but I am hoping someone here might have experienced this before. Is there some Excel limitation I'm encountering that I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I am aware of but I did notice something strange. Excel Refuses to open the file in the first attempt. Says there is some problem with the file and if I enable editing then the file can harm my comp. My wild guess is that the Excel file is not being created properly which might be causing this issue?

Comment: I get the same error, but it's always been present, and considering Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is not currently maintained, I think I'm going to have to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this appears to just be some weirdness on behalf of Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer. I recommend that anyone reading makes the switch to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), as the error is not present when generated with that library.